# Python Selenium having trouble clicking <a href="#"...> with javascript

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following HTML:

```
<ul id="TopMenuTabs">
    <li>...</li>
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#" onclick="formaction='topbasic';document.frmEPO.button.value='topbasic'; if( ValidateForm() ) document.frmEPO.submit(); return false;">Reports</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to click the second button on a top menu of a site using the following code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@id='TopMenuTabs']/li[1]/a").click().perform()
```

When I run it, the url adds the "#" to the end so it's recognizing the click() command, but doesn't seem to actually click it or execute the javascript. I've tried using time.sleep for up to 30 seconds, to ensure it isn't just a page-loading problem, with no success. It always moves on to the next line and errors out because the page hasn't changed. Not really sure what to try next!

Comment: I've also used just .click(), same result

Comment: Ok so apparently when you use an index for an element, it's not 0-indexed, so it should have been ...li[2]... I'm all set now!